# How to let the servlet container (Tomcat) interrupts/destroys a servlet request?

Tags: java, servlets

I am new in Servlet, I used the following code to read some inputStream,

```
class MyServlet implements Servlet{
  void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res){
  InputStream inA, inB, inC;
   //...
   inA.read(); // May block
   inB.read(); // May block
   inC.read(); // May block
   // ...
   }
 }
```

How to let the servlet container (Tomcat) interrupts/destroys MyServlet after some configurable time.  And in this case which method(s) will it call?

thanks in advance,,,

Comment: What's the functional requirement? Right now you're asking how to achieve a solution of which you think that it is the solution for your functional requirement. But this solution stinks somewhat. You really don't want to have a servlet run for minutes and for sure not to have the control over interrupting a request. Again, elaborate the functional requirement, then we may come up with much better solutions.

Comment: for issues, my service shouldn't process more than specific time, if so it should terminate. i.e. do nothing and then retrying in the specified time till it success. I hope my functional requirement is clear ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call those methods, the container does.

I'd wonder why you would do this.  Do you really want to re-read those files with every request?  If you need the contents, I'd prefer to see you read them in the init method and cache them.

Comment: thanks,,,how container  interrupt service servlet method ?
I just need to interrupt service method if it takes a specific time
anymore suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you can do this with java.nio or wrapping it in a Timer.  But the servlet API should not be part of the solution.  It's an IO issue.

Comment: is timer Save to use in servlets?

Comment: If you create it locally inside the service method it'll only be visible to the thread associated with that HTTP request.  Should be okay.  Only shared state is problematic.

Comment: Is there is reference indicate that it is safe to use timer in servlet ?,,,thanks for your effort

Comment: No reference, just your knowledge regarding thread safety and the docs for something like FutureTask or Timer: http://doc.javanb.com/javasdk-docs-6-0-en/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do that using Tomcat (or another servlet engine).

The simplest way may be to spawn off the time-consuming process in a separate thread, invoke that and time out on that invocation. You can do that easily by using a [FutureTask](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) object and calling [get()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) on it, specifying a timeout. You'll get a TimeoutException if the task takes too long, and you can use the servlet to report this (nicely) to the user.

e.g. (very simple)

```
FutureTask f = new FutureTask(new Runnable{...});
try {
   Object o = f.get(TIMEOUT, UNITS)
   // report success
}
catch (TimeoutException e) {
   // report failure
}
```

Comment: Yes. That's not a problem and a common solution to these sort of problems

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps the best approximation without using your own threads: The service method can throw [javax.servlet.UnavailableException](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/UnavailableException.html) which will signal container that the servlet is not available temporarily or permanently.